# $\operatorname{AD}$ and the measurability of $\omega_1$

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, ultrafilters, determinacy

Are there proofs of the measurability of $\omega_1$ (under $\operatorname{AD}$) that do not use Turing degrees nor the $\Sigma_1^1$ boundedness lemma?

I've been struggling to find an "elementary" proof of this fact. Note that I consider the proof of "Assume $\operatorname{AD}$. Then every ultrafilter is $\sigma$-complete" to be elementary. 
The club filter on $\omega_1$ is thus readily seen to be a $\sigma$-complete filter, but the "ultra" part seems not to be so easy to prove (it's for an introductory course on $\operatorname{AD}$, without too much knowledge of recursivity etc.)

Comment: AD= axiom of determinacy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_determinacy (just for context, $\omega_1$ is not measurable in ZFC).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure this will work for you, but there's a way to recast the Turing argument so that it avoids recursion theory; if this is the reason you want to avoid the Turing argument, this might be the way to go.

Namely, instead of working with Turing degrees, work with a coarser reducibility, which is easier to explain. For anything coarser than Turing reducibility, the cone property holds by the same argument, and we can define an analogous $f$ mapping reals to ordinals.

Specifically, here are the details for one particularly nice notion, *relative projectiveness* (or *projective reducibility*). Say a real $r$ is projective relative to a real $s$, and write $r\le_{p}s$, if there is a second-order sentence $\varphi(x, Y)$ in two variables with no parameters - where $x$ is a natural number variable and $Y$ is a set variable - such that $$r=\{n: \varphi(n, s)\}$$ holds. (There are many equivalent ways to phrase this.)

It's easy to check that this is, in fact, a reducibility (in particular, that it's transitive - this isn't hard, but it's worth doing explicitly), and so yields a *degree structure* $\mathcal{D}_p$. And by the same proof as in the Turing case, we have that any "$\equiv_p$-invariant" set of reals either contains or is disjoint from a cone in $\mathcal{D}_p$. So the "projective cone" filter on $\mathbb{R}$ is an ultrafilter. Moreover, by taking infinite joins, it's clear that this ultrafilter is countably closed.

Now we want to port it over to $\omega_1$. We'll use the same trick as in the Turing case: for a real $r$, let $f(r)$ be the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\alpha$ is not projectively definable in terms of $r$ (formally, there is no well-ordering of $\mathbb{N}$ of ordertype $\alpha$ which is projective relative to $r$); such a real exists, since there are only countably many projectively definable ordinals relative to a given real.

*Note that this uses a small bit of choice - namely, that $\omega_1$ is regular. But this is provable in ZF+AD, so that's fine. Note that DC is **not** known to be provable in ZF+AD (although [it does follow from ZF+AD+V=L$(\mathbb{R})$](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2274099?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)) so we can't use it here.*

By the same argument as in the Turing case, the filter gotten by "porting over" the projective cone filter via $f$ is a measure on $\omega_1$.

---

Another natural reducibility to consider is *relative constructibility*. In many ways this is actually more natural than relative projectiveness; however, it makes things a bit trickier, since you have to show that $\omega_1$ is inaccessible from reals assuming AD.

However, this isn't hard - if $\omega_1^{L[r]}=\omega_1$ for some real $r$, then we have $\vert\mathbb{R}\cap L[r]\vert=\omega_1^{L[r]}=\omega_1$ (the first equaltiy since $L[r]$ satisfies condensation appropriately); but then $\mathbb{R}\cap L[r]$ is a counterexample to the perfect set property.

Comment: And the fact that $f$ is well-defined comes from $\omega_1$'s inaccessibility to the reals. I guess this could work. I'll wait and see if other approaches are given but this seems fine.

Comment: @Max Yes, that's a good point - I should have made that explicit in my answer. (Although, if you work with something narrower than constructibility, it can become trivial - so if your students have already seen e.g. projective definability, you could use the relative version of that and not have to prove anything about $\omega_1^V$.)

Comment: I'm sorry I may be a bit tired but how would you do it with projective definability ?

Comment: @Max Projective definability can be turned into a reducibility - a real $r$ is *projectively reducible to* a real $s$ if there is some projective (second-order) formula $\varphi(x, y)$ - where $x$ is a natural number variable and $y$ is a real variable and $\varphi$ has no other parameters - such that $s=\{n: \varphi(n, s)\}$. It's not hard to see that this is indeed a reducibility (in particular, it's transitive), and the usual proof of the cone theorem goes through; we now let $f$ map $r$ to the sup of the ordinals projectively definable from $r$, and it's immediate that this is countable.

Comment: We could also use first-order definable, instead of projective: look at formulas in the language of arithmetic, augmented by a new unary predicate meant to stand for "$s$". But I suspect the projective version will be more natural, since the projective hierarchy already shows up in descriptive set theory.

Comment: I suspect you wrote an "$s$" instead of a "$r$". But I get the idea. Obviously indeed, with DC $\omega_1$ has cofinality $\omega_1$ so that this is quite obvious. I'd actually rather go for this rather than for the constructibility thing, because I fear they might not be so at ease with constructibility just yet. Could you make an "answer" of it (as you did for constructibility) ?

Comment: @Max Dangit, you're right; too late to fix now.

Comment: @Max I edited. Incidentally, your argument that AD implies that $\omega_1$ is regular isn't right: it's not known that ZF+AD implies DC. But we don't need DC to get that. First, let me show that the union of countably many countable sets of reals is countable. Consider this game: player I plays $i\in\omega$, and player II has to then enumerate the elements of $A_i$ (on their $\langle n, k\rangle$th move, they play the $k$th bit of the $n$th real they're building). Clearly player I can't win, so by AD player II has a winning strategy; but this amounts exactly to an enumeration of $\bigcup A_i$.

Comment: Alright, now suppose $A_i$ is a countable set *of countable ordinals*, for each $i\in\omega$. We play the same game, only now player II is building an array of reals, *each of which codes an element of $A_i$*. By the same argument, player II must have a winning strategy, but this winning strategy gives an enumeration of $\bigcup A_i$ - in fact, an enumeration via specific reals coding those ordinals!

Comment: Thanks for your editing ! Concerning $\omega_1$'s cofinality, I'm assuming DC throughout the course, so that's not an issue. Although proving that $\omega_1$ is regular with AD is also quite nice.

Comment: Could you comment on this part of your message : " we have |\mathbb{R}∩L[r]|=\omega_1^{L[r]}=\omega_1 (the first equaltiy since L[r] satisfies condensation appropriately);"

Comment: I meant "$|\mathbb{R}∩L[r]|=\omega_1^{L[r]}=\omega_1 $"

Comment: @Maxtimax Sorry, I just saw this. Are you familiar with the proof that V=L implies CH? It uses the *condensation lemma*: that if $M\prec L_\alpha$ then $M\cong L_\beta$ for some $\beta<\alpha$. *(Actually there are a few different, equivalent ways to phrase this.)* An analogous result holds of $L[r]$, for any real $r$, and this means that $L[r]$ always satisfies CH (in fact, GCH, and much more).

Comment: The proof I know doesn't use this (at least I don't think so). But I found another proof of the inaccessibility of $\omega_1$ to the reals, which only uses $\Sigma_0$ absoluteness and $L[r] \models AC$ so I'm satisfied with it (sorry for not validating your answer until now, by the way)